# html accessibility - screen reader not reading updated content?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, voiceover, screen-readers

I have sort of a basic accessibility question.

So I have the following:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend id="legend">content to read</legend>
    <div>
        <input type="text">
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

When I tab onto `input`, my screen reader (MacOS VoiceOver) reads the legend's "content to read".

But if I change that text to something else using JavaScript, the screen reader still reads the original "content to read" every time instead of "updated text" as below. I also added `aria-live="polite"` but to no avail.

```
<fieldset>
    <legend aria-live="polite" id="legend">updated text</legend>
    <div>
        <input type="text">
    </div>
</fieldset>

<script>
    // example js that updated content above
    document.getElementById("legend").textContent = "updated text"
</script>
```

I am quite new to html accessibility, and thought it would be reasonable to expect the updated content to be read...otherwise how can I make it happen?

Thanks for your input,

---

EDIT(Dec 11, 2022):
Per recent comment, I decided to include the full code in the codesandbox below.

[codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-html-css-js-sandbox-forked-t8q2by?file=/index.html)

To reproduce the issue:

1. Tab onto `radio 1` to hear `content to read` being read.
2. Tab onto button `Click me to change text` to change the legend text from `content to read` to `updated text`
3. Tab onto radio button again to hear `content to read` still being read, when `updated text` is expected.

Comment: Can you explain why you would want to change a fieldset’s legend? In general, changing labels and roles does not work in most assistive technology, and it’s code smell. Your input is lacking a label, is that on purpose?

Comment: Screen readers are supposed to take into account the new text when it's updated. Without aria-live, it just won't be read automatically on change, but should normally be read the next time you land on it. However, your input has no label, maybe the problem comes from there, as a label is normally required.

Comment: Input needs to be in a form element and the form and legend need to be linked so the leged describes the input/form.

Comment: hey all, sorry for leaving out the label and form tag. I have made an edit to include the full code sandbox for reference. Hopefully this helps. Thanks.